Return null when multiple values has same mode
Sharing one sample code . For column b as u can see both values{1,2} has same frequency{2} so mode is returning both values but I want null . Which logically means that it is unable to find one unique value which is most occuring.
import polars as pl


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pl.DataFrame( { "a": [1, 1, 2, 3], "b": [1, 1, 2, 2],})

    # print(df)
    print(df.select(pl.col("b").mode()))


You could try using a pl.when().then() construct.
df.select(
    pl.when(
        pl.col("b").mode().len() == 1
    ).then(
        pl.col("b").mode()
    )
)

shape: (2, 1)
┌──────┐
│ b    │
│ ---  │
│ i64  │
╞══════╡
│ null │
│ null │
└──────┘

If you prefer a single null, you can append .unique() to the closing parenthesis of .then().

Hello @hericks I am trying to understand logic here.after finding mode .what is purpose of Len over that?

If the mode is unique, then pl.col("b").mode() will return a single element and the return value will be of length 1. The code above is equivalent to pl.when(pl.col("b").mode().len() == 1).then(pl.col("b").mode()).otherwise(None) (note the trailing .otherwise(None)). This just overwrites the value with null if the initial condition is not met.
